# 100 Amp Shed Workshop from 200 Amp House Panel 120' Direct Bury Cable

Tags: subpanel

I am interested in some advice/support on installing a 100 Amp Main Breaker Sub Panel approximately 120' from my 200Amp Main Panel in my basement.  I have a background and experience in electrical wiring but this is only my second garage/shed wiring experience.  My plan is to install a 100 AMP breaker in the Main Panel (Basement) using 2-2-4 Aluminum Direct bury cable from mail to Sub Panel.  Trenching the yard to a depth of 24" per NEC Code for direct bury cable.  I will only be using Electrical PVC Conduit (grey)conduit for all above ground wire and building entry points.  I welcome your input and recommendation on my plan to help keep me 100% in compliance with NEC Codes.  Thank You.

Comment: I don't see that you have really asked a question here, so you might want to edit your posting and phrase it clearly as a question.  Also, let me suggest to you that you go with a conduit vs. a direct buried cable.  The extra expense is minimal, you might need more power in the future, and the conduit will go a long way toward protecting your buried cable from damage.

Comment: Trenches are expensive, conduit is cheap. Direct burial is never a good idea, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

First, a few general thoughts:

- You'll need four conductors, not three. Two hots, neutral, and a separate ground.
- Also need to add a grounding electrode system at the outbuilding. (two ground rods, concrete-encased electrode, buried copper wire, copper water pipe, etc)
- It seems short-sighted to direct-bury cable. You could put it in an enormously over-sized 2" conduit for under US$1 per foot. 1-1/2 is adequate and, though it might be a tough pull, even 1-1/4 SCH 40 PVC meets the fill requirements for holding 3x1 ga (hot, hot, neutral) plus 1x4 ga (ground).
- Don't forget to mount the riser conduits to the buildings (strut and conduit clamps, for example).
- Some detached buildings provide prime roof real estate for PV generation. Does yours?  You might do well to drop an extra conduit in the trench so that PV wiring can be carried back from the outbuilding to the main panel in the future.
- Will you ever want any low voltage connections between the buildings? Security, fire alarm, networking? If "maybe" then "add another conduit."
- Last rule of wiring: buy the wire last! Too often people buy the wire first, then partway through the project become aware of something that makes the already-bought wire less-ideal or even inappropriate/unusable.

I think your 2-2-4 cable is undersized. It's true that the 90 degree C column of NEC table 310.15(B)(16) pegs the ampacity of 2 ga aluminum at 100 A, but you can't use the 90 degree C column because your breakers' terminals will be rated for just 75 degree C.

The 2-2-4 cable sounds like a USE type cable? I'm not certain that's allowed to be used for a feeder. Also not sure that a feeder is allowed to down-size the neutral conductor the way services are.

For reference: I've just finished a 100 ft 100 A feeder similar to yours; I used 3x1 ga plus 1x4 ga aluminum THWN conductors in conduit. The 4 ga was for grounding, and although it could have been #8 copper or #6 aluminum, I used 4 ga because I needed a few for another circuit and because at that size and heavier one can re-mark a "hot color" conductor for neutral/ground use. I put a wrap of green tape at each end and that black wire suddenly became a ground wire.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're doing a lot of stuff right, but I see a couple of ordinary mistakes there.

### Think BIG

Putting a 100A-rated panel on a 100A feeder is like buying 85 mph-rated tires when you live in Wyoming and actually do drive 85 mph. 112 mph tires are better, and you don't *have to* drive 112 mph :)

The other thing is, most consumers *wildly* underestimate how much stuff 100A of feeder can support.  120V circuits only load one leg, and you can greatly oversubscribe a panel because not that many things run at the same time. (you don't use welder *and* lathe *and* table saw/dust collector *and* EVSE all at the same time; nor heater *and* A/C). 800A worth of handles is perfectly plausible, but you need the panel spaces for that!

And of course "100A" panels only go up to about 12 spaces or so.

So most novices make the mistake of far too few spaces.  It's a very cheap problem to solve when buying the panel initially, but a major chore to fix later. So while we don't often aim to "spend your money", we strongly recommend an outlandishly large panel - 30 spaces is not too many.

The outbuilding needs a disconnect switch. It can be indoors. The cheapest way to do that is pick a subpanel *with a main breaker*, but we don't care about the trip rating since it's only a disconnect.  So a 100A feeder supplying a 200A-breakered subpanel is fine.

"But I was hoping the main breaker in the outbuilding would trip first" - that wouldn't have worked anyway.  And it's unlikely to occur at all with a feeder this big.

### Your wire needs to be bigger.

You actually need 100A rated wire, and the #2 you picked is only good for 90A.   So you'll need #1 aluminum (or downbreaker to 90A).

By the way, I know how you got that #2 aluminum number.  That applies when you order a 100A service from the electric company with a 100A meter and main breaker.  Wires which carry the entire service can take an 83% favorable derate.  So that number is all over the Web on the "how-to" pages, but it's wrong for a feeder.

This rule is why your 200A meter-to-main service entrance wiring is 4/0 Al instead of the 250 kcmil that's plainly stated in NEC.

### Ground wire and cables

Wrong cable type. That is service entrance wire made for the power company's side of the meter/main disconnect.  There is no ground wire on the power company side of the meter.... but there certainly must be one on the NEC-regulated side.   Also, downsizing the neutral isn't allowed unless the line is dedicated to specific large loads known to have reduced neutral requirements - it doesn't work for a general purpose feeder.

For 100A, ground needs to be #8 copper (can be bare) or #6 aluminum (cannot be bare).

So you'll need 1/1/1/6 cable, of course no such thing is made.  Past experience of others hunting down such wire *in a cable* has been frustrating. Most cables are sold for *services* and because of the aforementioned discount, 100A uses #2 and 125A uses #1/0.  So #1 is an inbetween size not made in USE or MH cables. (can't use SER; it's not underground rated).

You could direct-bury XLP/USE-2/RHH/RHW-2 type individual wires.  That will be easier to pull through the conduit sections also.

By the way, the conduit sections must be fully assembled and glued before any wires are put into them.  That means it must be "pullable" - all sweeps, no more than 360 degrees of sweep between access points, access points must remain accessible, etc.  On the upside, this lets you break the job into easy chunks and you can easily take a break mid-job.

Indoors, consider using EMT metal conduit, which screws together like an Erector Set, meaning if you need to rework, you can just take it apart and redo, with minimal waste of material.

### Conduit is worth considering anyway

Since you're going to use PVC all the way except underground, i.e. for the building run and stub-ups, you might think about running it underground too.  That will make it an all-conduit routing, and make it easier to change or add wires in the future.  (not least, *fiber-optic* is allowed in power conduits for data, though we'd advise laying a second conduit alongside for that purpose so you can use copper data lines).

This relieves you of the duty of picking a particular *cable* that works.  You can now assemble your hots, neutral and ground out of appropriate wires such as THHN, XHHW or XLP/USE-2/RHH/RHW-2, depending on what's cheapest :)

Comment: I agree with going with a larger panel, but just FYI with respect to *"And of course "100A" panels only go up to about 12 spaces or so."*, I did a quick search at Big Orange and found some 30-space/60-circuit (so they are true 30s) listed as 100A panels. Plenty more 12s, of course.

Comment: Note that direct bury *quadruplex* USE is a thing.  It's intended for 3ph direct buried services, but works just as well for split-phase feeders (it also counts as individual wires for conduit fill purposes, which is helpful)